# Splunk appendcols is not querying all events

Tags: splunk

I am trying to calculate the average number of errors by calculating `events(with error)` / `total events`.

Here is my query

```
...| stats count(_raw) as Total
   | appendcols [search .... error
       | rex "(?i)^[^\\.]*\\.\\w+:\\s+(?P<FIELDNAME>.+)"
       |stats count as errors by FIELDNAME ]
   |eval average = errors/Total|sort -errors
```

Result:

```
FIELDNAME   errors    Total  average
abc            10                 
def             2
ghi             2      30      0.0666
jkl             1
mno             1
```

Expected Result

```
FIELDNAME   errors    Total  average
abc          10        30     3.3          
def           2        30     0.66
ghi           2        30     0.0666
jkl           1        30     0.33
mno           1        30     0.33
```

Why is `total` not calculated for all the events?

Answer (score 0):

Your first search, which calculates a total, creates a single result. The subsearch outputs multiple results. It joins first result to the first total. Since the subsearch has more results, it creates additional events (with null totals) to contain the remaining results.

But here is a more efficient way to run your search, with no need for subsearches at all:

```
yoursearchhere
| rex "(?i)^[^\\.]*\\.\\w+:\\s+(?P<errorCode>.+)"
| stats count as errors by errorCode
| eventstats sum(errors) as total
| eval average = round(errors/Total,2)
| sort -errors
```

Although I am at a loss with your "expected results table" - shouldn't the first line read

```
abc          10        30     .3
```

since 10/30 = .333333? And you aren't calculating an average anyway, you are calculating the percentage.

If you want to add the average, do this:

```
yoursearchhere
| rex "(?i)^[^\\.]*\\.\\w+:\\s+(?P<errorCode>.+)"
| stats count as errors by errorCode
| eventstats sum(errors) as total avg(errors) as average_errors
| eval percentage = round(errors/Total*100,2)
| sort -errors
```